# Python 3.6 - Parse json response with dict inside dict

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, parsing, dictionary

I'm being driven insane because I can't parse this `json` response. I've tried many different things and nothing works properly... Could you help me?
The this is the file I am parsing:

```
{
    "info": {
        "funds": {
            "asset": {
                "net": "12516.000",
                "total": "0"
            },
            "borrow": {
                "btc": "0",
                "cny": "0",
                "ltc": "0"
            },
            "free": {
                "btc": "0",
                "cny": "0",
                "ltc": "0",
                "eth": "0"
            },
            "freezed": {
                "btc": "0",
                "cny": "0",
                "ltc": "0",
                "eth": "0"

            },
            "union_fund": {
                "btc": "0",
                "ltc": "0"
            }
        }
    },
    "result": true
}
```

I just want something like:

```
#What I want to get the "net" which is "12516.000", so I tried this:
funds = response['info']['funds']['asset']['net']
```

`funds = response[0]` returns `{` as answer, and `funds = response[1]` gives me `r` as a response, and finally if I try `funds = response['info']` I get this type error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually parsed the JSON, it's just being read as a string, so `response[0]` returns the first character of the JSON string, or `{`. To parse the JSON string,

```py
import json
json.loads(response)['info']['funds']['asset']['net']
```

which is the pattern you're expecting. More details about the `json` library can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the answer of **@kevmo314**.

Sometimes your **response** may contain leading and trailing whitespaces. You can remove it using **strip()**.

> **Note:** when you get response, basically you get as a string (in some cases, it may be different) which can represent Python objects like **list**, **dictionary** etc.
>
> So it's necessary to convert them back into their original form before performing any operations on them.

Below is the working code.

```
 import json

 response = response.strip()
 response = json.loads(response)

 funds = response["info"]["funds"]["asset"]["net"]
 print(funds)
```

Comment: Now I understand... How to do is better than just do, really appreciate, so thanks!! Working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks **@Victor**. **json** module is really nice. I love it too much. Enjoy programming.